# JDK7: Diamond inference syntax confusion

Tags: java, type-inference, java-7, diamond-operator

Try to compile the following code in JDK7:

```
import java.nio.file.*;

public final class _DiamondSyntaxErrors {
  public interface InterfaceA<T> {
  }

  public abstract static class ClassA<T>
      implements InterfaceA<T> {
    protected ClassA() {
    }
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    // no error
    InterfaceA<Path> classA = new ClassA<>() {
    };

    // error: cannot infer type arguments for SimpleFileVisitor<>
    FileVisitor<Path> visitor = new SimpleFileVisitor<>() {
    };
  }
}
```

Why doesn't the second usage of the diamond syntax work?

What's the big difference to the first usage?

Comment: Margus, he's using a new feature [planned](http://code.joejag.com/2009/new-language-features-in-java-7/) for Java 7.

Comment: Java 7 is not final yet, I would presume that this is a bug of sorts and you could probably report it to Oracle. I doubt anyone here will be able to shed much light on it.

Comment: `@BjornS`: Ok, I'll report a bug. I just have the experience that lots of "bugs" are no bugs but misunderstandings of something, so I asked here first ;)

Comment: Seeing how the problem is solved, maybe you could put an answer saying "It was a bug. Now it is fixed." and accept that answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filed a **[bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6996759)**.
Someone else filed **[similar bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6996914)** with same example ;)
It was fixed now (**[here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/tl/langtools/rev/bce19889597e)**).

Comment: Yes, this is probable the only possible "correct" answer, but since I'm the author, I have 2 days till I can accept this ;)